# Howcome form value does not reset?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form.

[image: Form]

This returns back and loads its value which is correct,

however when I start typing it only returns its value plus one letter from the `onChange`.

here is what I mean

[image: return 1 letter]

How do I clear the value of the form when the onChange is executed? I have tried clearing the form using config.setStateVar('') which still does not seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
 const onChange = (e, config) => {

    config.setStateVar('')


    const value = e.target.innertext ? e.target.innertext
    : e.target.value

    config.setStateVar(value)

  }
```

Full Code:

```
const editCriticalObjects = props => {

  const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
  const criticalObjectsId = query.get('id')

  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)

  const [editCriticalObjects, setEditCriticalObjects] = useState([])

  const [criticalObjectTitle, setCriticalObjectTitle] = useState('')
  const [criticalObjectDomainName, setCriticalObjectDomainName] = useState('')
  const [criticalObjectType, setCriticalObjectType] = useState('')

const [findVal, setFindVal] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadCriticalObjects() {
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const results = await get(`get_critical_objects?id=${criticalObjectsId}`, user.user)
      setEditCriticalObjects(results)
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }
      onLoadCriticalObjects()
  }, [])

  const assetIdObject =  editCriticalObjects.filter(obj => {
    if (obj.asset_id === criticalObjectsId) {
      return obj
    }
      return assetIdObject
  })


  const configs = [
    {
      label: 'Title',
      name: 'Title',
      value:   assetIdObject.map(item => item.asset_id),
      field: SinglelineTextfield,
      uniqueIdentifier: 0,
      stateVar: criticalObjectTitle,
      setStateVar: setCriticalObjectTitle,
    },
    {
      name: 'type',
      uniqueIdentifier: 1,
      label: 'type',
      value: assetIdObject.map(item => item.type),
      field: SinglelineTextfield,
      stateVar: criticalObjectType,
      setStateVar: setCriticalObjectType,
    },
    {
      name: 'Domain',
      label: 'Domain',
      value:  assetIdObject.map(item => item.Domains),
      field: SinglelineTextfield,
      uniqueIdentifier: 2,
      stateVar: criticalObjectDomainName,
      setStateVar: setCriticalObjectDomainName,
    }
  ]

  const criticalObjectParams = {
    asset_ids: criticalObjectTitle,
    asset: true,
    merge: true,
  }

  console.log(criticalObjectParams)

  const onChange = (e, config) => {
    const value = e.target.innertext ? e.target.innertext
    : e.target.value

    config.setStateVar(value)

  }


  const onSubmitClick = async () => {
    loading.setLoading(true)

    await verifiedPost('post_critical_objects', criticalObjectParams, user.user)
    loading.setLoading(false)
  }

  return (!editCriticalObjects ? null :
    <PageWrapper title={`Edit Critical Object: ${criticalObjectsId}`}>
      <div className='Main Card EditCriticalObjectFormWrapper'>
        {configs.map((config, k)=> {
          const Field = config.field
            return (
              <React.Fragment key={k}>
                <Field
                  style={{ marginBottom: '15px'}}
                  name={config.name}
                  placeholder={config.name}
                  value={config.value}
                  initialValue={config.value}
                  initialValues={config.value}
                  uniqueIdentifier={k}
                  label={config.label}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, config)}
                />
              </React.Fragment>
            )
        })}
          <Button
            className='Button Dark Main'
            text='Submit'
            onClick={onSubmitClick}
          />
      </div>
    </PageWrapper>
    )
}

export default editCriticalObjects
```

Comment: Why do you want to clear the value of the form if it has a value in it already, should it not be editable? I'm also confused as to why you're setting ```innertext``` in your onChange function. The ```value``` property will contain the full value of the input, i.e. its current value plus the char you entered. Clearing the state will not affect the value stored in it.

Comment: Yes, it does, I am using it as a placeholder which can be easily edited. so I want to make that value editable which it is not. How do I clear the value of the input when the user starts typing on the field? If that makes more sense